# Romance fantasy manhwa in which the female lead and the male lead have a baby at the end, possibly named Sofia

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

I can’t remember the name of this manhwa I read a few years ago.

All I can remember is that the female lead (FL) had brownish/reddish hair and green eyes and the male lead (ML) had silver hair and it included magic. Of course, that’s very vague, so I think the FL wasn’t a noble from before and no was about to kill her but there was a spell that made him love her instead?? I think the FL was named after a bird or something of the sort and I think the spell was related to her mom?? I think the magic was also drawn in like circular symbols?? The FL and ML also have a baby at the end, possibly named Sofia?? I’m not too sure of the name.

That’s all I can tell you. If you recognize it, please help!

Comment: Can you start from the beginning and explain everything you remember about the plot? For example, I can't make sense of "the fl wasn’t a noble from before and no was about to kill her"

Comment: @user168284 - Just to clarify, did you mean to type "ml" (male lead) instead of "no" in the sentence quoted in [Laurel's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279677/romance-fantasy-manhwa-in-which-the-female-lead-and-the-male-lead-have-a-baby-at/279693#comment771448_279677)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[What's Wrong with You, Duke?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/whats-wrong-with-you-duke)***...?

> The cruel Duke Dreux of Faucigny is a lovestruck puppy around Nöel — all thanks to a random magic spell that was cast just as he was about to execute her. But with the spell’s power now waning and on the fritz, his shifting moods zip from dramatic professions of eternal love to cold threats of death. Exhausted from the emotional whiplash, Nöel must find a magic spell to not only save herself but also her enchanting fairytale marriage before she loses her beloved and bewitched “Ru” forever.
>
> [image: Promotional art for "What's Wrong with You, Duke?"]

The protagonist, Nöel Montbelliard, has reddish-brown hair, green eyes, and is the illegimate daughter of a count. Her father and the household servants treated her with contempt and the only one who loved her was her biological mother, who died when Nöel was young.

One day, war broke out when the Emperor of Rouergue commanded his cousin and right hand man, the silver-haired Duke Dreux of Faicigny, to rid the land of every last rebel, which included Nöel's family. The Duke had a reputation for slaughtering his enemies without mercy, and knowing this, Nöel's family fled their mansion without her, leaving her alone to 'protect' it.

As she awaited the Duke's arrival, Nöel was afraid, but remembered that when her mother was on her deathbed, she told Nöel that "when he raises his sword to strike you down, be brave, and look directly into his eyes."

The Duke's men subsequently stormed the mansion and brought Nöel before him. Laying on the floor were the bodies of the servants who'd already been killed. The  Duke raised his bloody sword, apparently intending to execute Nöel as well, but she made a silent wish to live and a magic circle appeared on the floor, sending a bolt of energy into the Duke's chest. He then dropped the sword, professed his love for her, and asked her to marry him.

The story skips forward a year and Nöel is now married to the Duke and living with him at his castle, but is insecure, as she didn't want this marriage and worries that the Duke's attitude towards her may change if the mysterious spell affecting him wears off. The Duke is mostly doting towards her, and refers to her as his little bird, or songbird, or skylark, but occasionally shows flashes of his old, cold-hearted self, as if the spell is indeed wearing off.

We subsequently learn, through a flashback, that Nöel's mother was a gypsy fortuneteller and a creator of charms and talismans who was taken by Nöel's father as his concubine, but died from years of mistreatment by his jealous wife. Before she died, Nöel's mother taught her about the world of magic. Nöel no longer recalls the details, but reads books in the Duke's library in order to learn how to recreate the magic circle that appeared when he was about to kill her.

In the final chapter (133), Nöel gives birth to a daughter named Sofia.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/whats-wrong-with-you-duke/info).

Comment: Yess! It is! Thank you so much! I was looking for it for forever! Thank you so much! ^^